# How can run a script tag in html page which is already generated by an external javascript file

Tags: javascript

extenal javascript file:
var someVariable="document.write('JavaScript text');";

and output should be: 
JavaScript text

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Show your files (high level is fine.) Do you want to run JS that you create dynamically? Use eval (if you can't re-think your solution.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `document.write().` `write()` only gets executed once. For other javascript functions you use `eval()` but again it won't work for `write()`

**code is:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var somevariable="<script>document.write('This is a javascript variable');</script>";
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(somevariable);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i am trying to put all code but after paste code the tags are hide.....